# Как изменить поле в ldap в питон? Вот поля

Tags: python, ldap

Как изменить поле (в моём случае fax)в ldap в питон? Вот поля -

```
    base = "имя"
    score = ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE
    filter = "(&(mail=))"
    attrs = ['mail', 'fax', ...]
    result_set = []
    
    ldap_result_id = 
    lconn.search_ext(base, score, 
    filter, attrs)
    lconn = ldap.initialize('имя')
```